# using pandas dataframe group by columns, multiply and add each current row & previous row based on month

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, numpy

am having one dataframe, dataframe has 16 columns cust_id, order_id, value, date, jan, feb, mar, apr, may, june ... upto dec month are the columns will be there

Using group by cust_id & order_id  - I have to multiply & add for each current row and previous rows for last 11 month Values columns

If previous month values are not present, that particular month should be considered as 0
like for Ex: In date column first row was starting from 12th[Dec] month so previous months(11) values Nov, Oct, Sep, Aug, Jul, ... are not present in dataframe for that calculation should be 0

```
cust_id  order_id    date     value   output 
 1008      001    2020-02-01   3000    2200   [3000*0.4 +3000*0.0 +2000*0.5+1000*0.0+0+0+0+0+0+0+0]
```

```
Input Dataframe 
    import pandas as pd
    import numpy as np
    import datetime

    df = pd.DataFrame({'cust_id': ['1008'] * 4 + ['1009'] *4,
                    'order_id': ['51'] * 4 + ['192'] * 4,
                    'Date': ["2020-12-01",
                             "2021-01-01",
                            "2021-02-01",
                            "2021-03-01",
                            "2020-12-01",
                            "2021-01-01",
                            "2021-02-01",
                            "2021-03-01"],
                     'Value': [1000, 2000, 3000, 3000, 6000, 9000, 180, 400],
                       'Dec': [0.1]*2+ [0]*2 + [0.5]*2 + [0.5]*2,
                      'Jan': [0.1]*2+ [0.5]*2 + [0.3]*2 + [0]*2,
                      'Feb': [0.2]*2+ [0]*2 + [0.1]*2 + [0.5]*2,
                      'Mar': [0.8]*2+ [0.4]*2 + [0.1]*2 + [0.2]*2,
                      'Apr': [0.3]*2+ [0.5]*2 + [0.4]*2 + [0.6]*2})

Output Dataframe 
data
###
  cust_id   order_id    Date    Value    Output
0   1008    51     2020-12-01   1000      100
1   1008    51    2021-01-01    2000      300
2   1008    51    2021-02-01    3000      1000    
3   1008    51    2021-03-01    3000      2200
4   1009    192   2020-12-01    6000      3000
5   1009    192   2021-01-01    9000      5700
6   1009    192   2021-02-01    180       3090
7   1009    192   2021-03-01    400       3170
```

```
I tried the below code but not working
df['output'] = df.groupby['cust_id','order_id']['Date'].apply(lambda x:(x['values']*x['jan']+x['values']*x['dec']))

but in loop it should work with jan,feb,mar -- dec

Even i tried below one as well
df_1 = pd.DataFrame(
    (df.Value * df[4:][:, None]).reshape(-1, df.shape[1]),
    pd.MultiIndex.from_product([df.index, df.index]),
    df.columns
)
df_1
```

Comment: can you please also post the example of the dataframe without `---- `, as they do not allow to copy and test without manually retyping whole the data

Comment: hi again mate, - I tried to look at it and cannot get linked results of your output and dataframe example.... is `cust_id = 'legal_entity`, order_id missing, + how you managed to get `values 1000` for the date `2020-12-01` and other dates? Plus, your calc ` output = 1000*0.4 + 0` looks strange.... Shouldn't it be `output = 220*0.1(Jan) + 0(Nov)` ???

Answer (score 0):

I did my best to understand and to apply your example data.
Not sure if it is correct, but I placed column `order_id` to dataframe as it was missing.
The code below has explanations/comments for each step.
Finally, if I have Not understood your formulas/calculations correctly, just adjust them to your needs.
I am sure your result is possible to achieve with smaller amount of steps, - but I am not yet in that level `pandaninja`.

P.S. Be careful, the code below is for one calendar Year only, - if you want to apply it for longer period, - check the data sorting before applying calculations.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'legal_entity': ['1008'] * 4 + ['1009'] *4,
                'order_id': ['001'] * 4 + ['009'] * 4,
                'key_account': ['51'] * 4 + ['192'] * 4,
                'Date': ["2020-12-01",
                         "2021-01-01",
                         "2021-02-01",
                         "2021-03-01",
                         "2020-12-01",
                         "2021-01-01",
                         "2021-02-01",
                         "2021-03-01"],
                 'Value': [1000, 2000, 3000,  3000,  6000, 9000, 180, 400],
                   'Dec': [0.1]*2+ [0]*2 + [0.5]*2 + [0.5]*2,
                  'Jan': [0.1]*2+ [0.5]*2 + [0.3]*2 + [0]*2,
                  'Feb': [0.2]*2+ [0]*2 + [0.1]*2 + [0.5]*2,
                  'Mar': [0.8]*2+ [0.4]*2 + [0.1]*2 + [0.2]*2,
                  'Apr': [0.3]*2+ [0.5]*2 + [0.4]*2 + [0.6]*2})

# creating dictionary of short Month names and coresponding numbers
d_months = dict(zip(pd.date_range('2021-01-01', freq='M', periods=12).strftime('%b'), range(1,13)))
print(d_months)
{'Jan': 1, 'Feb': 2, 'Mar': 3, 'Apr': 4, 'May': 5, 'Jun': 6, 'Jul': 7, 'Aug': 8, 'Sep': 9, 'Oct': 10, 'Nov': 11, 'Dec': 12}


# melting dataframe to get Monhs from headers into rows, -  placed in the column 'Val_Month'
df2 = df.melt(id_vars=['legal_entity','order_id', 'key_account', 'Value', 'Date'],var_name = 'Val_Month', value_name = 'Smal_Vals')
print(df2)
   legal_entity order_id key_account  Value        Date Val_Month  Smal_Vals
0          1008      001          51   1000  2020-12-01       Dec        0.1
1          1008      001          51   2000  2021-01-01       Dec        0.1
2          1008      001          51   3000  2021-02-01       Dec        0.0
3          1008      001          51   3000  2021-03-01       Dec        0.0
4          1009      009         192   6000  2020-12-01       Dec        0.5
5          1009      009         192   9000  2021-01-01       Dec        0.5
6          1009      009         192    180  2021-02-01       Dec        0.5
7          1009      009         192    400  2021-03-01       Dec        0.5
....
38         1009      009         192    180  2021-02-01       Apr        0.6
39         1009      009         192    400  2021-03-01       Apr        0.6

# in the col: 'Val_Month', - replacing short Month names by relevant monthly numbers (stored in the dictionary 'd_months')
df2['Val_Month'] = df2['Val_Month'].map(d_months)

# creating new column: 'Month_FromDate' with relevant month numbers based on column 'Date'
df2['Month_FromDate'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(df2['Date']).month

# check if previous month values is NaN (missing), - result: True/False
# shift(1) checks values from cell above or literally shifts the column by periods/cell numbers in the parameter field ().
check_prev_month_value = df2['Value'].shift(1).isnull()

# your calculations/formulas. val1 used if previous month is missing
val1 = df2['Value']*df2['Smal_Vals']

# val2, if previous month value is present. And again, shift(1) takes values from the cell above
val2 = (df2['Value']*df2['Smal_Vals']) + (df2['Value'].shift(1) * df2['Smal_Vals'].shift(1))

# applying formula val1 if previous month values is NaN (Bolean=True) and val2 if Not
df2['Output'] = np.where(check_prev_month_value, val1, val2)

print(df2[['legal_entity', 'order_id', 'Date', 'Value', 'Smal_Vals', 'Output']])

 legal_entity order_id        Date  Value  Smal_Vals  Output
0          1008      001  2020-12-01   1000        0.1   100.0
1          1008      001  2021-01-01   2000        0.1   300.0
2          1008      001  2021-02-01   3000        0.0   200.0
3          1008      001  2021-03-01   3000        0.0     0.0
4          1009      009  2020-12-01   6000        0.5  3000.0
5          1009      009  2021-01-01   9000        0.5  7500.0
6          1009      009  2021-02-01    180        0.5  4590.0
7          1009      009  2021-03-01    400        0.5   290.0
8          1008      001  2020-12-01   1000        0.1   300.0
9          1008      001  2021-01-01   2000        0.1   300.0
10         1008      001  2021-02-01   3000        0.5  1700.0
....
38         1009      009  2021-02-01    180        0.6  3708.0
39         1009      009  2021-03-01    400        0.6   348.0
```

As per comments, in the end, to summarise the values Monthly, use the line below. As you calculate one month's value per each 5 months vals, you get extra 5 columns (values) per each month.

```
df3 = df2.pivot(index=['legal_entity','order_id', 'key_account', 'Value', 'Date'], columns='Val_Month')

df3.to_excel("test.xlsx")
```

Comment: And yes, if you noticed, renaming short months to numbers is not necessary... I left it in mistake from my previous tests.

Comment: it creates more rows after the initial `.melt` function. You can use `.pivot` or `.pivot_table` to get the shape of the table back by placing `Val_Month` as an argument for column

Comment: nope, - I have updated the answer with the final row

Answer (score 0):

Using group by cust_id & order_id -
I have to multiply & add for each current row and previous rows for last 11 month Values columns.

## code for dataframe

```
import datetime

df = pd.DataFrame({'cust_id': ['1008'] * 4 + ['1009'] *4,
            'order_id': ['51'] * 4 + ['192'] * 4,
            'Date': ["2020-12-01",
                     "2021-01-01",
                    "2021-02-01",
                    "2021-03-01",
                    "2020-12-01",
                    "2021-01-01",
                    "2021-02-01",
                    "2021-03-01"],
             'Value': [1000, 2000, 3000, 3000, 6000, 9000, 180, 400],
               'Dec': [0.1]*2+ [0]*2 + [0.5]*2 + [0.5]*2,
              'Jan': [0.1]*2+ [0.5]*2 + [0.3]*2 + [0]*2,
              'Feb': [0.2]*2+ [0]*2 + [0.1]*2 + [0.5]*2,
              'Mar': [0.8]*2+ [0.4]*2 + [0.1]*2 + [0.2]*2,
              'Apr': [0.3]*2+ [0.5]*2 + [0.4]*2 + [0.6]*2})
```

Output

```
  cust_id   order_id    Date    Value    
  0   1008    51     2020-12-01   1000      
  1   1008    51    2021-01-01    2000      
  2   1008    51    2021-02-01    3000          
  3   1008    51    2021-03-01    3000      
  4   1009    192   2020-12-01    6000      
  5   1009    192   2021-01-01    9000      
  6   1009    192   2021-02-01    180       
  7   1009    192   2021-03-01    400
```

## First we make a separate Column for months and remove date column

that 's the only we need

```
month=[]
for i in range(0,8):
    month.append(df['Date'].apply(lambda x:x.split('-'))[i][1])

df['month']=month
df.drop(['Date'],axis=1,inplace=True)
```

output-:

```
    cust_id order_id    Value   Dec     Jan     Feb Mar Apr month
0   1008    51          1000    0.1     0.1     0.2 0.8 0.3 12
1   1008    51          2000    0.1     0.1     0.2 0.8 0.3 01
2   1008    51          3000    0.0     0.5     0.0 0.4 0.5 02
3   1008    51          3000    0.0     0.5     0.0 0.4 0.5 03
4   1009    192         6000    0.5     0.3     0.1 0.1 0.4 12
5   1009    192         9000    0.5     0.3     0.1 0.1 0.4 01
6   1009    192         180     0.5     0.0     0.5 0.2 0.6 02
7   1009    192         400     0.5     0.0     0.5 0.2 0.6 03
```

## Code for generating Output

```
ans=[]
for i in range(0,8):
    if month[i]=='12':
        ans.append(df['Value'][i]*df['Dec'][i])
    if month[i]=='01':
        ans.append(df['Value'][i]*df['Jan'][i]+df['Value'][i-1]*df['Dec'][i])
    if month[i]=='02':
        ans.append(df['Value'][i]*df['Feb'][i]+df['Value'][i-1]*df['Jan'] 
        [i]+df['Value'][i-2]*df['Dec'][i])
    if month[i]=='03':
         ans.append(df['Value'][i]*df['Mar'][i]+df['Value'][i-1]*df['Feb'] 
         [i]+df['Value'][i-2]*df['Jan'][i]+df['Value'][i-3]*df['Dec'][i])
df['Output']=ans
```

Output:-

```
    cust_id order_id    Value   Dec Jan Feb Mar Apr month   Output
0   1008    51          1000    0.1 0.1 0.2 0.8 0.3  12     100.0
1   1008    51          2000    0.1 0.1 0.2 0.8 0.3  01     300.0
2   1008    51          3000    0.0 0.5 0.0 0.4 0.5  02     1000.0
3   1008    51          3000    0.0 0.5 0.0 0.4 0.5  03     2200.0
4   1009    192         6000    0.5 0.3 0.1 0.1 0.4  12     3000.0
5   1009    192         9000    0.5 0.3 0.1 0.1 0.4  01     5700.0
6   1009    192          180    0.5 0.0 0.5 0.2 0.6  02     3090.0
7   1009    192          400    0.5 0.0 0.5 0.2 0.6  03     3170.0
```

Range in for loop vary according to the number of rows in dataframe.

This is code works for the available  months in dataframe and for other months we just need some more code for other months calculations similar to this one

for group columns use df.groupby() for group any columns of your choice
for this data frame they already grouped.

For any queries feel free to comment
Thank you
:)